# Need shell script to extract sub-string starting with a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have to extract sub-string starting with a pattern `"Branch_"`.

**Sample IO**

```
Input1:  /home/user/Branch_1.1/fsw/make
Output1: /home/user/Branch_1.1

Input2:  /home/user1/code/Branch_1.1_new/new_dir/code_changes
Output2: /home/user1/Branch_1.1_new

Input3:  /home/john/project/new/Branch_5.6_code/make/files
Output3: /home/john/project/new/Branch_5.6_code

Input4:  /home/danny/Branch_code/new_files/make
Output4: /home/danny/Branch_code
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title and textual description don't quite line up with your sample inputs and outputs. Which is correct? (The substring *starting with the pattern* would be everything *after* `Branch_`, but you appear to want everything up to and including the path component matching it).

Comment: Please post  a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash regex for this:

```
s='/home/john/project/new/Branch_5.6_code/make/files'    
[[ $s =~ ^(.*/Branch_[^/]*).* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

/home/john/project/new/Branch_5.6_code

s='/home/danny/Branch_code/new_files/make'
[[ $s =~ ^(.*/Branch_[^/]*).* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

/home/danny/Branch_code
```

Comment: Hi anubava, Its perfectly working.. thanks a lot :) :)